# how to stop this bogon host running from my macbook?

Tags: network, high-sierra, ethernet, mac-address

I have noticed from my macbook a new hostname is exposed with the name `bogon`

[image]

even if I block this mac address on the router, it comes up with a new one.
And  do not have any clue where is it coming from ?

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bogon is an illegitimate IP address that falls into a set of IP addresses that have not been officially assigned to an entity by an internet registration institute, such as the Internet Assigned Number Authority (IANA). Bogons arise as a result of a misconfiguration or intentional misuse that fools recipients about its source IP address. The term bogon is used as slang and is derived from the word bogus.

Prevention of bogons.

Many internet service providers (ISP), firewalls and intrusion prevention systems block bogons. This can be accomplished through bogon filtering, or the practice of assigning access control lists (ACL) or Border Gateway Protocol (BGP) blacklists to a device. A list of bogons can be obtained from a variety of sources including HTTP, BGP peering, routing registries and the DNS.

This is not an unusual problem and much has been written about it [here](https://team-cymru.com/community-services/bogon-reference/), [here](https://ctovision.com/help-bogons-are-in-my-networks/) and [here](https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/bogon). These are commonly found as the source addresses of DDoS attacks. I don't know enough about them to do more than refer you to these sites. There are ways to prevent these from showing up on your machine.

a Google search on Bogon returns many other sites with helpful information.

Comment: I tried filtering using blocking mac address from router, turns out a chinese vivo v8 plus phone at home stopped connecting to the wifi, so i checked the mac address and it was of that phone. Does that mean this phone was creating a bogon,  what is strange earlier vivo phone used to show up separately than the bogon.